# PlantUML component diagam port

Tags: uml, plantuml, component-diagram

Is there any possible way to create component port in the component diagram?

If port has to be attached to only one arrow, its easy, because I can use `#--` arrow.

```
interface y
[x] #- y
```

The problem is, if I try to attach to arrows to one port. I tried to use `rectangle`, but its not on the border then.

```
rectangle " " as P
[Component] - P

interface I1
interface I2

P - I1
P -- I2
```

Do you know any better workarounds?

Comment: Do both ports have to  be on the right (east) side of Component?  Otherwise why mot try `[Component] #- I1` and `[Component] #-- I2`

Comment: That's not the case I have meant. I'd like to render two interfaces being attached to one port. In your example, both interfaces are attached to two different ports.

Comment: Maybe you can point the Rectangle in the port of `[Component]`, then point `I1` and `I2` to the rectangle.. so update it to `[Component] #-- P`..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although a bit late for TO perhaps helpful for someone else.

I managed to create ports on components with the following approach:

```
@startuml
skinparam componentstyle uml2
left to right direction

component X {
    port " " as x_out
}

'u for layouting it more nicely, 0) for lollipop
x_out -u0)- [Y]
x_out -u0)- [Z]

@enduml
```

However I experienced a bad layout of the port itself, means when a component has several ports it will start looking messy. But hey at least its a port with multiple connections.

Result looks like:

[image]

Comment: Don't know when port was added or where it is documented, but this is exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: You can add `skinparam ComponentBackgroundColor #BUSINESS` and 
`skinparam ComponentBorderColor #firebrick` and `skinparam ComponentFontStyle normal` commands to give the ported component the same look as the others.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get a satisfactory result, at least in my case, this way:

```
@startuml
Interface -# MasterComponent
component MasterComponent {
[Subcomponent1] - [Subomponent2]
}
MasterComponent - [Subcomponent1]
@enduml
```

Comment: Yes, I mensioned hash connection as a solution, when only one interface uses the port. My question is, how to draw two interfaces using a single port (for example both provided and required)?